# How can I layer images in PyQt using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Let's say I have two images, image A and image B. Using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView, how can I draw image A to the background, and layer image B on top of image A?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html)s that you draw your images on you can use [setZValue](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setZValue) to set custom stack order.

If you only need background on the scene you can take advantage of [scene layers](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsscene.html#SceneLayer-enum), for example use [backgroundBrush](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html#backgroundBrush-prop) to change the background and then draw other things on top of that.

Comment: Three of your links are "reserved for customers" which I'm assuming wasn't the case when you answered. Please consider providing an example so that future visitors to this question will not have the same problem.